# How to I get around this "AllowBypassKey" in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have inherited this access database at work and need to make changes to it. When you open the DB it has a form that pops up and everything else is hidden. There is an AllowByPassKey macro installed, and I was able to view the VBA by importing that database into a new access database, but I can't figure out how to get around this to be able to make changes needed. Can anyone help?

Thanks so much,

```
Function ap_DisableShift()
'This function disable the shift at startup. This action causes
'the Autoexec macro and Startup properties to always be executed.

On Error GoTo errDisableShift

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim prop As DAO.Property
Const conPropNotFound = 3270

Set db = CurrentDb()

'This next line disables the shift key on startup.
db.Properties("AllowByPassKey") = False

'The function is successful.
Exit Function

errDisableShift:
'The first part of this error routine creates the "AllowByPassKey
'property if it does not exist.
If Err = conPropNotFound Then
Set prop = db.CreateProperty("AllowByPassKey", _
dbBoolean, False)
db.Properties.Append prop
Resume Next
Else
MsgBox "Function 'ap_DisableShift' did not complete successfully."
Exit Function
End If

End Function

Function ap_EnableShift()
'This function enables the SHIFT key at startup. This action causes
'the Autoexec macro and the Startup properties to be bypassed
'if the user holds down the SHIFT key when the user opens the database.

On Error GoTo errEnableShift

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim prop As DAO.Property
Const conPropNotFound = 3270

Set db = CurrentDb()

'This next line of code disables the SHIFT key on startup.
db.Properties("AllowByPassKey") = True

'function successful
Exit Function

errEnableShift:
'The first part of this error routine creates the "AllowByPassKey
'property if it does not exist.
If Err = conPropNotFound Then
Set prop = db.CreateProperty("AllowByPassKey", _
dbBoolean, True)
db.Properties.Append prop
Resume Next
Else
MsgBox "Function 'ap_DisableShift' did not complete successfully."
Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

Attempted to open with shift, could not get around bypass.

Comment: If you imported everything into a new db and can view VBA, why don't you edit that one? Not clear to me what you are asking for. This procedure is often password encrypted https://oasonline.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-disableenable-shift-bypass-key.html

Comment: Thanks, I am needing to use the current DB because of the linked tables these forms are connected to.

Comment: Did not import links?

Comment: The links imported, but for some reason are not updating when I test the update. It is saving to my current tables but not to the tables DB through the link. The DB I am working in holds all of the forms and queries, there is another DB with all of the tables, these tables get updated from the forms and queries.

Comment: Imported links work for me. And my links are to SQLServer backend. Sounds like you imported links as local tables, not links.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the database and see the popup form, open the VBA editor and execute then code in the direct window:

```
?ap_DisableShift()
```

Then open the database again.

Comment: Thanks for this, I should have also included that when the home form automatically pops up, all keyboard shortcuts are disabled, ribbon and objects are hidden. Even when I import the data to a new database and remove all VBA, when I open the home form, it locks down all other functions.

Comment: Don't you want to run `?ap_EnableShift()` close then hold down shift key when opening. Edit db, run `?ap_DisableShift()`, save and distribute.

Comment: Yes, but how can I open the immediate window to run this if all other functions have been disabled? I have tried Alt+F11 and Ctrl+G. Maybe there is another process that I do not know about? I don't have a lot of access experience.

Comment: You said the new db with imported objects allows you to view VBA. Would have to do it there. Sounds like you need to use this new db as your working master. Don't disable shift key until you have a way to re-enable, as in the password version of code I referenced. Or always have a master version that you never disable. Make a copy that you then disable shift key for distribution.